# Trying to understand how pandas merge works, right join specifically

Tags: python, pandas

I ran into a confusing result with a larger dataframe, have made a toy one that captures some of what's confusing me:

```
import pandas as pd
big_index = [123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130]
big_dat = {'year': pd.Series([2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2004], index=big_index),
      'other': pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], index=big_index)}
big_df = pd.DataFrame(big_dat)

year_index = [2003, 2000, 2001, 2002]
year_dat = {'a': pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index=year_index),
        'b': pd.Series([5, 6, 7, 8], index=year_index)}
year_df = pd.DataFrame(year_dat)
```

left, and inner merge work as I'd expect, but right and outer produce odd results:

```
merged_right = pd.merge(
    big_df,
    year_df,
    how='right',
    left_on='year',
    right_index=True
    )
merged_right
    other  year  a  b
123     a  2000  2  6
124     b  2000  2  6
125     c  2000  2  6
126     d  2001  3  7
127     e  2002  4  8
128     f  2002  4  8
129     g  2002  4  8
130   NaN  2003  1  5

merged_outer = pd.merge(
    big_df,
    year_df,
    how='outer',
    left_on='year',
    right_index=True
    )
merged_outer
    other  year    a    b
123     a  2000  2.0  6.0
124     b  2000  2.0  6.0
125     c  2000  2.0  6.0
126     d  2001  3.0  7.0
127     e  2002  4.0  8.0
128     f  2002  4.0  8.0
129     g  2002  4.0  8.0
130     h  2004  NaN  NaN
130   NaN  2003  1.0  5.0
```

In both cases index 130 gets associated with the 2003 year entry, for no apparent reason. I get that there's no "good" way to handle this since I'm assuming the index itself can't have NaN in it. I'd have expected this to just throw an error though, rather than returning that incorrect last column. I'm probably misunderstanding what pandas is doing under the hood. Tips to resources to figure out why this is going wrong would be as appreciated as code showing how to do it right.

Comment: Interesting, I would not have expected that either.  The most obvious workaround would seem to be to reset the index in "big_df" and then drop the index after the merge.  I would generally recommend merging index to index or key to key, just because the code looks cleaner that way, but it seems to me the way you did it should have worked OK as is.  You could probably open up a github issue for this if you are so inclined.  It definitely seems like this should not be default behavior

Comment: I dont see the problem? 2003 is in `year_df` and it would have to have an index value

Comment: @djk47463  why can't index be NaN?  What I believe OP is saying and what I agree with is last row for merged_outer should be `NaN   NaN  2003  1.0  5.0`

Comment: @JohnE what would be the benefit of having `NaN` in the index. Sure I understand that given the matching criteria thats what would be excepted, however I don't see why its necessary. Also if you do the merge on a column value and move the indexes to columns and use a standard index, then `merge()` continues to populate the index. So that must be what `merge` is attempting to do here, except it starts arbitrarily at 123

Comment: @djk47463  if the correct result is NaN then the correct result is NaN.  That's the benefit whether it is an index or column.

Comment: @JohnE I'll open a github issue and link back to it here. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17257